# JPA detaching entity still persists upon exit

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I am having trouble with autopersist using hibernate and spring-data. I have the following service where I create entityA.

```
@Service
public class entityAService {

    private final EntityARepository repository;

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "entityManagerFactory")
    EntityManager entityManager;

    @Autowired
    public entityAService(EntityARepository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    @Transactional
    public EntityA create(EntityA entityA) {
        repository.save(entityA);

        if (entityA.getRegisterExternal) {
            registerExternal();
        }

        return entityA;
    }

    private void registerExternal() {
        // we always need the entityA to be registered, however we don't want to not allow entityA creation if
        // the external register service is down. Thus we need to check for any non registered entityA's and try
        // to register them again.
        Set<EntityA> entities = repository.getEntityAWithRegisterExternalAndNotRegistered();

        ExternalRegister register = new ExternalRegister();
        for (EntityA entity: entities) {
            try {
                register.register(entity);
                entity.setRegistered(true);
                repository.save(entity);
            } catch (RegisterException e) {
                logger.warn("exception", e);
            }
        }

        return;
    }
}
```

Where I am having trouble is the "entity.setRegistered(true);" line for the entityA being created. When I walk through the process, after "registerExternal();" in the create method, I can see in the db that the newest entityA.registered = true. However after create method finishes, entityA.registered gets set back to false.

I have tried to call "entityManager.detach(entityA) and entityManager.clear() before the "registerExternal()" call, as well as "entityManager.refresh(entityA) after the call and nothing seems to work.

Is there a way to set an object to not autopersist?

Answer (score 0):

You are returning old entity from create method. Save method returns updated instance of an entity and you should always use that

Try to change to this

```
@Transactional
public EntityA create(EntityA entityA) {
    EntityA updated = repository.save(entityA);
    if (entityA.getRegisterExternal) {
        registerExternal();
    }

    return updated;
}
```

But registerExternal is also updating some entities. This should not be part of this create method. Create should handle only single create entity (SOLID principles).

Better remove registerExternal to background thread/Scheduler thread. But if you can not do that( but you should do it), fetch latest entity before returning from create

```
@Transactional
public EntityA create(EntityA entityA) {
    EntityA updated = repository.save(entityA);
    if (entityA.getRegisterExternal) {
        registerExternal();
    }

    // Fetch latest using ID of EntityA
    return repository.findOne(entityA.getId());
}
```